# Запрос к JSON не удается обработать ответ в PHP

Tags: php, json, api

Запрос вида

```
https://site.ru/api.php?key=123&method=balance&code=123456
```

Ответ

```
{"balance":"9841","result":"Ok"} // Это оригинальный ответ ничего не меняю
```

Применяю такой код

```
$balance = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://site.ru/api.php?key=123&method=balance&code=123456'), TRUE);
echo $balance['balance']; // ПУСТО
var_dump($balance); // NULL
echo json_last_error(); // 4
```

Этот же ответ через сайт http://freeonlinetools24.com/json-decode отлично декодируется

```
Your json code is valid
    array (
      'balance' => '9841',
      'result' => 'Ok',
    )
```

Comment: вардампните `file_get_contents(...)` и посмортите что приходит.

Comment: @manitikyl Сделал `var_dump(file_get_contents('https://site.ru/api.php?key=123&method=balance&code=123456'))` Вывод `string(35) "{"balance":"9841","result":"Ok"}" `

Comment: Посмотрите код ошибки через `json_last_error()`

Comment: @nick Да это уже делал выше `echo json_last_error(); // 4`

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ - зайдите сюда и на свеженькой версии `PHP` проверьте свой код.

Comment: @Manitikyl file_get_contents Там к сожалению выполнить нельзя `<b>Warning</b>:  file_get_contents() has been disabled for security reasons in` Я выполняю этот код на PHP Version 7.2.8

Comment: `file_get_contents` точно возвращает json?

Comment: Вам проще тогда дать тому кто разбирается, чем нам сидеть и на кофейной гуще диагностировать проблему. Тем более это ваше не первое обращение, и как видите никто ничего не может вам сказать что у вас за мистика происходит.

Comment: @Manitikyl Я какбы и не против но тут Лички я так понимаю нету>?

Comment: По идее никаких проблем в самом коде нет. Все должно работать. Ошибка 4 это ошибка синтаксиса. У вас приходит через `var_dump` 35 символов, в то время как в строке 32 символа. Скорей всего это конечно пробелы, но попробуйте проверить ответ вот так `var_dump(trim(file_get_contents('https://site.ru/api.php?key=123&method=balance&code=123456')))`

Comment: @DanKud `string(35) "{"balance":"9841","result":"Ok"}"`

Comment: Странно, ведь в этой строке 32 символа `var_dump('{"balance":"9841","result":"Ok"}');` == `string(32) "{"balance":"9841","result":"Ok"}" `. Но я честно говоря не могу ничего сказать подробнее. Судя по тем данным, что вы дали все должно работать. Что еще за 3 лишних символа в этой строке понятия не имею. Возможно из-за этого и возвращается ошибка при попытки декодировать json

Comment: @DanKud Спасибо что подтолкнули нашел решение тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255993/how-do-i-remove-%C3%AF-from-the-beginning-of-a-file

Answer (score 2):

Помогло вот это

```
 $balance = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $balance);
```

Всем огромное спасибо. Так и не понял что-это за символы которые мешали декодировать ответ.